# How to specify number of characters in each line in python?

Tags: python

I have fasta file that contains two gene sequences and what i want to is to remove the fasta header (line starting with ">"), concatenate the rest of the lines and output that sequence in length of 50 characters per line. I made some progress but got struck at the end.

Here is my fasta sequence:

```
>Potrs164783
AGGAAGTGTGAGATTGAAAAAACATTACTATTGAGGAATTTTTGACCAGATCAGAATTGAACCAACATGATGAAGGGGAT
TGTTTGCCATCAGAATATGGCATGAAATTTCTCCCCTAGATCGGTTCAAGCTCCTGTAGGTTTGGAGTCCTTAGTGAGAA
CTTTCTTAAGAGAATCTAATCTGGTCTGTTCCTCGTCATAAGTTAAAGAAAAACTTGAAACAAATAACAAGCATGCATAA
>Potrs164784
TTACCCTCTACCAGCACCAATGCCTATGATCTTACAAAAATCCTTAATAAAAAGAAATCCAAAACCATTGTTACCATTCC
GGAATTACATTCTGAGATAAAAACCCTCAAATCTGAATTACAATCCCTTAAACAAGCCCAACAAAAAGACTCTGCCATAC
```

And the output that i want is something like this

```
>conc
AGGAAGTGTGAGATTGAAAAAACATTACTATTGAGGAATTTTTGACCAGA
TCAGAATTGAACCAACATGATGAAGGGGATTGTTTGCCATCAGAATATGG
CATGAAATTTCTCCCCTAGATCGGTTCAAGCTCCTGTAGGTTTGGAGTCC
TTAGTGAGAACTTTCTTAAGAGAATCTAATCTGGTCTGTTCCTCGTCATA
AGTTAAAGAAAAACTTGAAACAAATAACAAGCATGCATAAACCATATGGC
ATTTTGCATCCATTTGTGCATTTCATTTAGTTTACTTGCATTCATTCAGG
```

My script so far is

```
final = list()

with open("test.fa", 'r') as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line.startswith(">"):
            final.append(line)

final2 = "".join(final)

with open("testconcat.fa", 'w') as fh_out:
    fh_out.write(">con")
    fh_out.write("\n")
    fh_out.write(final2)
```

How can i make sure that i only write 50 characters in each line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) library

```
import textwrap
final2 = "".join(final)
print '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(final2, 50)
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with large files, if you do the joining, slicing etc. in memory, you may end up getting weird issues as you'll be consuming relatively much more memory for `appending` each line and then `splitting` them again into equally divided chunks before actually writing to file.

I think the best way to do avoid such issues is operating on file not on memory, in other words, you should write as you read at the same time.

```
>>> with open('test.fa', 'r') as r, open('testconcat.fa', 'w') as w:
...     for line in r:
...         if not line.startswith(">"):
...             w.write(line.strip())

>>> with open('testconcat.fa', 'r+') as w:
...     chunk = 50
...     i = 0
...     while next(w, None):
...         w.seek(((i + 1) * chunk) + i)
...         w.write('\n')
...         i = i + 1

>>> cat testconcat.fa
AGGAAGTGTGAGATTGAAAAAACATTACTATTGAGGAATTTTTGACCAGA 
CAGAATTGAACCAACATGATGAAGGGGATTGTTTGCCATCAGAATATGGC
TGAAATTTCTCCCCTAGATCGGTTCAAGCTCCTGTAGGTTTGGAGTCCTT
GTGAGAACTTTCTTAAGAGAATCTAATCTGGTCTGTTCCTCGTCATAAGT
AAAGAAAAACTTGAAACAAATAACAAGCATGCATAATTACCCTCTACCAG
ACCAATGCCTATGATCTTACAAAAATCCTTAATAAAAAGAAATCCAAAAC
ATTGTTACCATTCCGGAATTACATTCTGAGATAAAAACCCTCAAATCTGA
TTACAATCCCTTAAACAAGCCCAACAAAAAGACTCTGCCATAC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When i tried your script, the first part works but the second one doesn't. Can you please look into it

Comment: No error but the script doesn't finish running even with that small file above and also when i looked at the output, the first line is 50 characters but not the other lines

Comment: let's continue the discussion in a chat room here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84896/how-to-specify-number-of-characters-in-each-line-in-python